# What exactly is static mesh component in Unreal Engine?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I have recently started learning Unreal Engine as a complete beginner, and I got stuck on this thing called static mesh component.
Is it ok to assume that this components decides the shape of the actor that the component is on?

Comment: Welcome to https://stackoverflow.com/. Please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask . 

You should provide a reproduceable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This is really more something better answered by a YouTube tutorial series for beginners. I recommend to check out the official Unreal channel.

Answer (score 1):

A mesh is a collection of vertices, edges, and faces that describe the shape of a 3D object.

In Unreal Engine you have static and skeletal meshes.

Static meshes are the simpler, for example you would use a static mesh for a chair or any other inanimate object.

Skeletal meshes are intended for more complex objects, for example for characters. They have a set of interconnected bones (skeleton) that you can use to animate the model.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!
So 
-static meshes are made of one single component
-skeletal meshes are made of several, which are all able to be controlled individually
-mesh allows builders to decide each components' physicals characteristics
Are these understandings correct?

Comment: Depends on what you understand by components, probably not. A simple way to think about this is that skeletal meshes are just static meshes but with the capability of playing animations.

Comment: Just to add to this, the static mesh component can be (and usually is) responsible for rendering a material(s) on the mesh itself.

Answer (score 0):

As a dumb way of putting this:

Static Mesh Component is the actual figure of a thing. It also cannot be animated. Skeletal Mesh Components can be animated.

As an extension, there are Geometry Brushes which can be created before even using static meshes for level design. They should not be in the final design tho, you can upgrade them to static meshes.

"Geometry Brushes are the most basic tool for level construction in Unreal. Conceptually, it is best to think of a Geometry Brush as filling in and carving out volumes of space in your level. Previously, Geometry Brushes were used as the primary building block in level design. Now, however, that role has been passed on to Static Meshes, which are far more efficient. "

https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/Basics/Actors/Brushes/